# How to Get ajax to stop appending a hashed location to a URL

Tags: html, ajax

I'm trying to determine where in my set of JavaScript files would I edit to make the urls of my site stop being appended with a "#home" to every portion of the site, or specific pages. I thought it was in the "deeplinking:" value of Pretty Photo, but then I realized that wouldn't make sense for that js to manipulate a URL in a normal page (a gallery, yes, and I have another site where that DID stop giving URLs to images in the Pretty Photo gallery, but not for regular page content). I cannot seem to locate it in the fw_scripts.js - which controls the majority of the site. I also tried to inspect element in FF to see what event handlers might be on the HTML tag, but to no avail.

Where would I find the javascript to edit to make the url's of any index.html file in a specific folder STOP appending a #home tag?

See what I mean here http://clients.runningh20.com/mf

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: In http://clients.runningh20.com/mf/js/fw_scripts.js see `$(window).load`

Comment: thanks..I'll check right into that!

Comment: actually doesn't seem to work. I even deleted that .js file altogether and it still loads with a "#home" etc. appended to the URL.

Comment: The link in your question is still loading that script. If you remove it there and still see it happening I'll check again what it could be.

Comment: I put it back after trying that.

Comment: I actually need other stuff in that script. BUt it was weird that I removed that script from being called and it was still loading the urls with the location hashed.